# Datetime: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I understand from the comment below that this is a method that needs to be called, however I do not understand this entire concept of filtering by datetime and no problem on the internet proves to have the answer. Can someone please walk me through what needs to be done to filter by year.

This code is used to filter rows between certain range of dates. I wish to print out only the rows that lie in between these dates when I am printing my dataframe however run into the error (listed below my code). I am unsure how I should convert my data to match the correct data type. Any ideas on how I can run the code to only print out the rows within this range?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


df = pd.read_csv('otd.csv', encoding='latin-1')
dd = df['Delivery Date']
startdate = pd.to_datetime("12/31/2014").date
enddate = pd.to_datetime("01/05/2015").date
print(df.loc[startdate:enddate])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 164, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
KeyError: <built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0x000000000BE91148>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4238, in get_slice_bound
    slc = self._get_loc_only_exact_matches(label)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4207, in _get_loc_only_exact_matches
    return self.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 164, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
KeyError: <built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0x000000000BE91148>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\khalha\eclipse-workspace\Test3\Project3\P3.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(df.loc[startdate:enddate])
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1478, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1866, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1511, in _get_slice_axis
    slice_obj.step, kind=self.name)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4107, in slice_indexer
    kind=kind)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4308, in slice_locs
    start_slice = self.get_slice_bound(start, 'left', kind)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4241, in get_slice_bound
    return self._searchsorted_monotonic(label, side)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4191, in _searchsorted_monotonic
    return self.searchsorted(label, side=side)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\khalha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 1230, in searchsorted
    return self.values.searchsorted(value, side=side, sorter=sorter)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Here is a sample csv file:

[image]

Comment: please edit your question to include the full traceback(error), including line number and file.

Comment: `datetime.date` is a method, you need to call it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman okay thank you!